# Add Time values in Array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Guys I have a question: 
I have an app that is connected to an external device with bluetooth.  I read data ( for example Acceleration )  from this device and save in array. These data are a flow of data like: 
`36,-562,-839,36,-563,-839,35,-562,-841,36,-562,-842,36,-562,-843,36,-562,-843...` ( this is the result of *console.log*)

What I wuold do, it is to add the variable time (the time is printed in second) for each three values of acc variable. Like:

Time + Acceleration
So the result should be:

`1 (sec) : 36,-562,-839,`

`10 (sec) : 36,-563,-839,`

`20 (sec) : 35,-562,-841,`

`30 (sec) : 36,-562,-842,..`

this is what I have:

`47840 : -1,-565,-839,-1,-566,-839,0,-565,-839,...`

47840 is the final time (the time when I press the stop button for the reading of data). The others data are the data about acceleration.

This is the code about this part.

```
constructor(props) {
this.state = {
time: null,
acc: [],
array_acc_sx: []}}

async setupNotifications1(device) {
const time = parseInt(
          Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64")
            .readUInt16LE(0)
            .toString(16),
          16
        );
const acc = [2, 4, 6].map(index => {
          const hex = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64")
            .readInt16LE(index)
            .toString(16);
          return Number.parseInt(hex, 16);
        });
        const accUpdate_acc_sx = [...this.state.array_acc_sx, ...acc]
        this.setState({ array_acc_sx:  accUpdate_acc_sx})
}

 stopConnection(time, array_acc_sx) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("Inizio stopConnection");
      Actions.registerattivita({
        time: this.state.time,
        array_acc_sx: this.state.array_acc_sx,})
      resolve("Connessione Interrotta");
      reject("Connessione non interrotta.");
    });
  }
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Scarpa Sinistra: </Text>
        <Text>{"Time:" + this.state.time}</Text>
        <Text>{"Acc:" + this.state.acc.join(" ")}</Text>
      </View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() =>
              this.stopConnection(
                this.state.time,
                this.state.array_acc_sx
              )
            }
          >
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
// ......
```

And in the page **RegisterAttivita**

```
    dataReceived(time,array_acc_sx){

        console.log("data acc_sx: " + this.props.time + this.props.array_acc_sx)
      }
```

How can I do?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved doing in this way:

```
const accUpdate_acc_sx = [...this.state.array_acc_sx, {time: this.state.time, acc: this.state.acc}]
```